# How to set a lock screen background by using intent.set()?

Tags: android, background-image

How can I set an image background on the lock screen like "black wallpaper" app available in play store?

Answer (score 0):

You can show wallpaper image in lock screen by using WallpaperManager[Added in API level 5]

Refer https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager

To set a Wallpaper in the Lockscreen use the flag **WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK**

Sample code:

`WallpaperManager.getInstance(this).setStream(inputStream, null, true, WallpaperManager.FLAG_LOCK);`